# Any way to make Text to Speech not mute the background audio, but just turn it down?

Tags: audio, gps, volume-control

I'm coming back to Android from iOS, having been a heretic for a few years.  I'm using a Nexus 6P.

The most jarring bit of the transition has been my phone's muting of music being played over bluetooth for text to speech.  I use Waze for driving, and listen to either music or podcasts during the drive.  Waze is a rather chatty program, but on iOS it was only slightly annoying.  iOS reduces the volume of whatever you're listening to when speaking;  my 'Droid is just flat out muting everything else to speak.

I find my Nexus' system to be really disorienting, especially during podcasts.  Suddenly, the voice I'm listening to changes, it's at a much louder volume than whatever the mixer on the podcast was set at, it shouts some street names at me, and then I get back to the podcast, and I've lost where the speaker was at in their point.  While I couldn't understand the podcast under the directions on iOS, I at least didn't get disoriented, because I could hear that the conversation was still "flowing" behind the directions.

Android's incredibly flexible, so I'm holding out hope that there's a setting or software I can install to do this.